# What are best practices around toggling between multiple wallets in bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-cli

I've created a couple wallets on Core to experiment with and want to dedicate one wallet as a live one.  What is the best way to move between those wallets inside the command line?  When I toggle to a wallet that is not the default in the GUI and try some bitcoin-cli wallet commands it get an error

```
Wallet file not specified (must request wallet RPC through /wallet/<filename> uri-path)
```

Is it just a matter of passing a wallet file name into the command? Or is there a better way to manage multiple wallets? Other best practices to a multi-wallet setup (i.e. don't)?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, thought I'd respond to my original question with what I've found out to this point. Haven't fully answered the original question yet but the approach I'm using at the moment to toggle between wallets is:

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="filename" [command]
```

Any other thoughts on best practices would be great!